# Rewrite schroedinger's equation in gravitational field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation

I'd like to consider the $H=mgx+\frac{p^2}{2m}$, and by the Schroedinger's equation:$H\psi=i\hbar \frac{d\psi}{dt}$. By making the transformation $$\psi(t) = e^{-\frac{imgx}{\hbar}t}\phi(t)$$ so that my new schrodinger's equation for $\phi(t)$ with a new time-depedent H that doesn't depend on x. I followed the hints and used the commutator between $p^2$ and $$e^{-\frac{imgx}{\hbar}t}$$ to make $$e^{-\frac{imgx}{\hbar}t}$$ disappear, but it didn't work out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using $\phi(p)$ (momentum-space wave function) instead of $\psi(x)$ (spatial wave function).

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): The Hamiltonian is unbounded from below. Classically the particle prefers $x=-\infty$.